# goroutine context canceledpanic

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have a service which creates `user -> user job -> user contact` and for user job and contact I wrap their task to create by wrapping go goroutine,

```
// create the user first.....

// then
go func() {

        clientJob.UserID = user.ID
        _, err = s.userJobRepository.Create(ctx, *clientJob)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        clientContact.UserID = user.ID
        _, err = s.userContactRepository.Create(ctx, clientContact)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
}()
```

I got `context canceledpanic` in that goroutine and my server stop after that, but if I don't use goroutine, it was fine and no error during creating,
anyone know why this happening and how to handle this?

Comment: The parent probably finished and canceled the context. If the context comes from the request handler, you need to either wait for your goroutine to finish before returning, or run your goroutine with separate context. But we can't tell without the surrounding code.

Comment: yeah, the parent has issue on `userJobRepository.Create()`, if we run goroutine with separate context, how we do it? @Marc

Comment: As mentioned: either wait for the goroutine to finish (at which point you don't need one), or create a new context just for the goroutine. Read the [docs for how](https://golang.org/pkg/context/), it even has a link to a blog post explaining how to use them.

Comment: which one func i should use? i have no idea, i am new for this, so that is why i asked this @Marc

Answer (score 0):

Each goroutine has its own stack. If a stack does not have a recover, the program will exit miserably. Recommendation: do not use panic to control business logic.

The question is: why? if `userJobRepository.Create` or `userContactRepository.Create` fails the user will never know it and your server would be dead.

Answer (score -1):

I can see the following 2 options:

Option 1:

You can create a new context for the go-routine instead of using the context that is already associated with the parent go-routine.

```
context.Background()
```

Option 2:

If you need to inherit values from the parent, context you will need to implement the context.Context interface in the following approach:

```
func DisconnectedContext(parent context.Context) (context.Context,   context.CancelFunc) {
    ctx := disconnectedContext{parent: parent}
    return context.WithCancel(ctx)
}

type disconnectedContext struct {
    parent context.Context
}

func (d disconnectedContext) Deadline() (deadline time.Time, ok bool) {
    return
}

func (d disconnectedContext) Done() <-chan struct{} {
    return nil
}

func (d disconnectedContext) Err() error {
    return nil
}

func (d disconnectedContext) Value(key interface{}) interface{} {
    return d.parent.Value(key)
}
```

Comment: i was using the option 1 but that context doesn't has deadline, so if i create the intasance of it, in my case, should i use that DisconnectedContext

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. For providing a totally disconnected context with deadline you should use context.Deadline(context.Background(), time.Now().Add(time.Minute)). The second option doesn’t apply because it only references the other context for looking up values, but doesn’t support deadline/timeout.